# How to use Boolean variable in c:if

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I am using this code in JSF.:

```
<c:if test="#{sV.done.booleanValue()}">
     <option value="#{sV.id}" selected="selected">#{sV.text}</option>
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{not sV.done.booleanValue()}">
     <option value="#{sV.id}">#{sV.text}</option>
</c:if>
```

`sv` is my class containing data (pojo), done is an `Boolean` variable, I want to display `option` tag with `selected` attribute if `sV.done` is `true`.
But I couldn't make it. Don't know where I am wrong.

Otherwise there can be something wrong with `c`, because `c:forEach` was not working before some time in my case in same page? It can be the reason? Where I am wrong?

Every time it displays option tag without selected `attribute`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As I mentioned in question, It seems to look like some other component/library is interfering in work of c:if, it didn't work in any case. I tried all the suggestions given above. Thanks to all for replies.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:  -

```
<c:if test="${sV.done == true}">...</c:if>  // or
<c:if test="${sV.done eq true}">...</c:if>  // or
<c:if test="${sV.done}">...</c:if>   // or
```

**And for negation (If sV.done is false):  -**

```
<c:if test="${! sV.done}">...</c:if>    /// OR
<c:if test="${not sV.done}">...</c:if>  /// OR
<c:if test = "${sV.done != true}">...</c:if>     // OR
<c:if test = "${sV.done ne true}">...</c:if>  // OR
```

For more on **if with operators** check out this link: -  [JSTL if](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/0080__If.htm)

Comment: Rohit, one thing I want to highlight is done is a `Boolean` variable not `boolean`, will it work? and second thing, I have tried this code, but didn't work for me :(.

Comment: Rohit, I was using `c:forEach` in the same page today, but was not working, then I needed to use `ui:repeat`, so do you think there is problem with `c`?

Comment: How were you using <c:forEach..>? As I don't think there can be any problem with <c:..> tag unless you use it correctly..

Comment: is your answer ok Rohit? $ or #?

Comment: I tried printing all of above and I am getting output from last one only `<c:if test="${!sV.done}">...</c:if>`, for sV.done = true and false.

Comment: @Patriks.. Yeah.. that will work for Boolean object.. But you are asking for if or forEach??

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is fine, provided that you're using EL 2.2. So, none of the JSTL `<c:xxx>` tags are been interpreted? You need to import the JSTL core taglib. It's unclear what view technology and JSTL version you're using, so here are import examples for both JSP and Facelets.

JSP with JSTL 1.0:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

JSP with JSTL 1.1/1.2:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Facelets 1.x with JSTL 1.1/1.2:

```
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
```

Facelets 2.x with JSTL 1.2:

```
<html ... xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, have you considered using a JSF `UISelectOne` component instead of fiddling with `<option>` elements yourself? You can find some concrete examples in [our `h:selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

Comment: Hi BalusC, I know about h:selectOneMenu but I want to show something like `http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/`, so I need to get records manually and display `selected="selected"` for number of `option`s, If you know any `h:` tag which can do this? display multiple selected list?

Comment: Is your JSTL problem solved? As to the functional requirement, just use that jQuery plugin then? Otherwise look at a 3rd party JSF component library such as PrimeFaces.

Comment: Many other programmers tried on my code too. but all says code is ok. so don't know yet what is wrong. still working on it.

Comment: Did you doublecheck all the versions? Note that a broken web.xml declaration would force a fallback modus.

Comment: Yes, I have this problem on only one page, in other pages c:if and c:forEach working find. Also I have included name spaced properly in the page.

Comment: Are you using Facelets and new to it? If so, make sure you understand the meaning of `<ui:composition>` (anything outside this tag is ignored).

Comment: I am not new to it. every thing working fine on other pages, problem is only on this page. Code wise things are ok.

Answer (score 3):

JSF and JSTL both access 'boxed' objects (Boolean, Integer etc) directly. No unboxing is necessary -- so you don't have to call booleanValue().

```
<c:if test="${sV.done}">...</c:if>
```

But actually, your whole approach could be better -- I don't render a  options in a page, without a list of options & a value. I don't write out loops & selection tests manually every time, there are tags or you can write a method to do this.

**Super hint:**  I have a class called Pair( String name, Object value) & library method HtmlUI.renderSelectOptions(), to output SELECT options from a list of these & a 'current' value.

Select combo-box may not really be the best representation for a boolean either? You could go with a checkbox.. But this is up to your UI design.

If you did want to go this way, you could switch *just the SELECTED attribute* inside the  tag. Easier than duplicating code for the entire , key & value.. For legacy code, I have a function that fulfills this exact requirement also :)

Hope this helps!  Vote me up.